# Wrap h1-h6 in a div

Tags: filters, title, the-content

So, I am using heading tags `h1`-`h6` on my site in various places, what I'd like to do is put a `div` around those tags using a WP function. Right now I am using some jQuery to get the job done, but I'm trying to minimize the amount of jQuery on my site, so I figured it'd be better to use some kind of `preg_replace` to find any h1-h6 tags and add an outer div.

My current jQuery looks like this: `$("h6, h5, h4, h3, h2, h1").wrap('<div class="title"></div>');`

I found some code that works for images, but I'm not sure how to tweak it, so I can use it for heading tags:

```
function outer_img_wrap( $content ) {
    $image = '/(<img([^>]*)>)/i';
    $wrapper = '<span class="featured">$1</span>';
    $content = preg_replace( $image, $wrapper, $content );
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'outer_img_wrap' );
```

Any help is appreciated. The function doesn't have to look like that, just found that for images and thought it was nice and simple.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Try a regular expression like: `<h.*?<\/h.>`.

Comment: @Nicolai - Thanks for the quick reply, I ran this through a regex validator and it finds everything, the header tags and the content, looking at my example code above this should work if I add it where the `$image` variable is right?

Comment: Yes, you have to modify the pattern variable, it should be like: `/(<h.*?<\/h.>)/ims`. Not sure about your issues, it works in my [test](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=108654).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code

```
function wrap_heading_with_div( $content ) {
    $heading = '/<h\d.*?>(.*?)<\/h\d>/ims';
    $wrapper = '<div class="title">$0</div>';
    $content = preg_replace($heading, $wrapper, $content);
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_heading_with_div' );
```

[Live Demo](https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/rtO#tab-preg-replace)

Answer (score 0):

The code you’ve posted is a great starting point. All you have to do is to change the expressions inside of it.

It’s a little bit trickier, because you have to replace opening and closing tag. I would go for something like this:

```
function wrap_headers_with_div( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace('/<h([1-6])>/', '<div class="title"><h$1>', $content);
    $content = preg_replace('/<\/h([1-6])>/', '</h$1></div>', $content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wrap_headers_with_div' );
```

Comment: There is no need to execute `preg_replace()` twice though.

Comment: @Nicolai but the code gets cleaner and easier to understand this way. And you get rid of all of the problems with multiline strings ;)

Comment: Let me respectfully disagree, we have the modifier `m` for that.

Comment: @Nicolai of course we have. And of course there are millions of ways to write this. Using two replacements is not an error and in my point of view it’s much easier to read, the person who uses it doesn’t need to understand modifiers (so it will be easier to modify for such persons), and it’s more reliable (for example it will still work when the HTML is not perfect). Of course you can also use only one replacement - it’s completely up to you.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż - Thanks for responding, I copied and pasted this into my `functions.php` and nothing happened. I found a regex validator and it all looks valid, it's finding and replacing the right things, not sure what the issue is. I even tried to replace `the_content` with `the_title` because the header tags are going around title tags...but no dice. When I inspect the page, it's as if the function is not even there...the header tags are there, there is just nothing around them.

Comment: This code will modify only the headers inside content. You can’t modify the title with such filter, because titles doesn’t contain header tags - these tags are printed by your theme. So you would have to check how your theme prints these titles and modify its code according to your needs.

Comment: That makes sense, I'll manually adjust the other values in my theme!